# how to send some data from fragment of one activity to another fragment of another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have read many links but all are passing data from one fragment to another activity or from one activity to other activity's fragment but I want to send from fragment of one activity to other fragment of another activity

Comment: Okay... If you can pass from a Fragment to an Activity, and a Activity to a Fragment, then you can pass from a Fragment to another Fragment through the Activity, right?

Comment: yes I can do that one but is this the only way..I mean is there not any other direct way.??@cricket_007

Comment: You could try to look into the EventBus library. Personally, haven't tried it, but many people recommend it

Comment: Actually I am a beginner programmer so don't know how to use external libraries....I think the way should be simple only it is like I am not only getting the solution@cricket_007

Comment: In my applications I use for those purpose static variables, have a look at the explaination I tried to give you below

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you could call `getActivity().startActivity()` from the first Fragment, with some extras set on that Intent, then from that second Activity, pass some arguments into the Fragment it creates.

So, from FragmentA

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityB.class);
i.setExtra("key", "hello world");  // for example 
getActivity().startActivity(i);
```

Then, ActivityB

```
onCreate() { 
    Intent i = getIntent();
    FragmentB frag = new FragmentB();
    if (i!=null) frag.setArguments(i); // pass along intent 
    // TODO load Fragment
```

And use `getArguments()` in the FragmentB

Comment: Alright, I'm on mobile, so can't test it, but that should be similar to the code you've seen in the examples you referenced

Answer (score 0):

If you have to pass datas all over the application or maybe between far activities/fragment like in your example, consider using some static classes (Even if in java there are no static classes. it's more a static field wrapper).

```
public class MyRunTimeDatas{
  private static String myStringData;
  private static int myIntData;

  //getters and setters
}
```

**Now, in `fragment 1` use**

```
MyRunTimeDatas.setMyStringData("my value");
MyRunTimeDatas.setMyIntData(69);
```

**Finally in `fragment 2` you can now call**

```
String myBeautifulString = MyRunTimeDatas.getMyStringData();
int myFantasticInt = MyRunTimeDatas.getMyIntData();
```

and you are done

Comment: As far as I know,the method you share is to transfer data from one fragment to another fragment in the same activity...but in my case it is fragment of different activity@Pier Giorgio Misley

Comment: @Ayaz - this is a Data Access Object. Since the variables are static, they sit in the application memory and can be accessed in any class.

Comment: @Ayaz it's as cricket_007 said: this is a separate class (a separate .java file) so it means you can access it from any class of your application

Comment: ok i got it....@cricket_007 @Pier Giorgio Misley..One more issue coming like how can i open fragment of other activity from fragment of one activity

Comment: @Ayaz honestly I don't get the benefit of not placing all fragments in the same activity. btw you can do it by opening from fragment1 the activity2 and then opening fragment2. but honestly is better to use a single activity instead of two

Comment: the exact scenerio is In my project I have 2 activities A and B. Activity A contains 2 Fragments and B contains 4 fragments.Now I have to open 1st fragment of Activity B from 2nd fragment of Activity A...Hope you got my scenerio...How should I proceed now on this?

Comment: @Ayaz can't you place all 6 fragments in activity A?

Comment: Actually I have taken 1 toolbar in Activity A and want to make changes in that toolbar(for other fragments)so I decided to take another activity with new toolbar and is making changes into it...and also I can't place that toolbar in fragments of Activity A as it is being used in all the fragments related to Activity A...So don't have other option but to take that toolbar in Activity A rather then any fragment

Comment: @Ayaz you can replace programmatically the toolbar by creating two and replacing each other based on which fragment is shown. anyway try the code I posted for the datas, so you can solve the problem. About the other problem, you have to open activity2 from fragment1 and then open fragment2 from activity2